# Allow Grafana charts iframe to only be accessed through trusted domain

Tags: iframe, reverse-proxy, grafana

I have successfully embedded Grafana iframes (Grafana charts) on the dashboard.
However, if that iframe is embedded onto another website, it can be easily accessed.
I want to **restrict usage of the iframe (Grafana charts) only to users of my application**.

I am struggling to find a proper solution.
What I found is creating a reverse proxy between Grafana and the website, and verify the server URL is related to my application, but I am still trying to find out a better (native Grafana) solution.

Comment: Use authentication with some SSO protocol and both apps will be sharing the same SSO session.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow up here. I have an application A, that basically has embedded Grafana charts as iframes. Since those charts are part of a dashboard, which users need to sign in into, I don't want others to access the iframes if used on another location. I don't need to authenticate the users (as I have my own system of handling that), but to display Grafana iframe only if the app that embeds it is on the authorized list.

Comment: `display Grafana iframe only if the app that embeds it is on the authorized list` - it sounds like security hole - attacker can configure own host header from authorised list and that means it can view Grafana data. So you really needs authentication, not just this buggy authorisation concept (IMHO: it is a task for `HTTP Content-Security-Policy`). Anyway, you are dev of the app, so you know what kind of risk level is acceptable.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your suggestion - to use auth with SSO protocol and both apps will be sharing the same SSO session? How would I do that?